# Interpretation of scalar moment of inertia used to derive the virial theorem using the Reynolds transport theorem

Tags: moment-of-inertia, kinetic-theory, virial-theorem

I have seen an uncommon derivation of the virial theorem and need some help understanding the physical aspects and interpretation.

For an integral form of an equation, 
$$I = \int_{V(t)} \alpha d^3 x $$
where $\alpha$ is any single-valued scalar, vector or tensor field and $V(t)$ is a finite volume (comoving volume), it can be shown that
$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \int_{V(t)} \left[\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla} \cdot (\alpha \vec{v}) \right]d^3x $$

where $\vec{v}$ is the flow velocity, which is the Reynolds transport theorem.

Furthermore, for a specific variable $\beta = \frac{1}{\rho}\alpha$ it can be shown using the zeroth order moment of the Boltzmann equation (which is valid for any distribution function) that 
$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \int_{V(t)} \left[\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial t} + \vec{v} (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \alpha ) \right]d^3x = \int_{V(t)} \rho \frac{D \beta}{Dt}d^3x$$
where $\frac{D}{Dt} $ is the comoving derivative.

Applying this relation (twice) to the scalar moment of inertia, namely setting 
$$ I = \int_{V(t)} \rho |x| ^2 d^3x$$
one can obtain the virial theorem (by making use of the Euler equations) :
$$ \frac{1}{2}\ddot{I} =  \int_{V(t)} \rho v^2 d^3x +  \int_{V(t)} 3P d^3x +  \int_{V(t)} \rho \vec{x}\cdot\vec{a} d^3x -  \int_{S(V)} P \vec{x}\cdot\vec{n} dS $$

First, let's have a look at each of these integrals and try to interpret them:

$\int_{V(t)} \rho v^2 d^3x $ should be twice the total macroscopic kinetic energy ; $2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}m v^2$ so to speak. (I know that it isn't exactly that, but I think it is a helpful intuitive interpretation ansatz.)

$\int_{V(t)} 3P d^3x $ should be twice the total microscopic kinetic energy ; $2 \cdot \frac{3}{2}PV = 2 \cdot \frac{3}{2}Nk_BT$ so to speak.

These first two integrals together give the kinetic term of the virial theorem: $2\langle K \rangle$.

Now this is where it gets tricky for me. The next two terms don't seem to fit in: I can't find a fitting physical interpretation for them like for the two above; Also it seems to me like they have other dimensions: The two integrals above should have the dimension of Energy, while the two below seem to have the dimension of energy times length. How is this possible? How is this explainable and understandable?

$\int_{V(t)} \rho \vec{x}\cdot\vec{a} d^3x $ should be the virial term $\langle V \rangle$, containing the acting forces inside the acceleration $\vec{a}$. But what exactly is this?

$\int_{S(V)} P \vec{x}\cdot\vec{n} dS $ is the often left out surface term $\langle S\rangle$. It comes from using the divergence theorem : $\int_{S(V)} P \vec{x}\cdot\vec{n} dS = \int_{V(t)} \vec{\nabla} \cdot (P\vec{x}) d^3x$

Furthermore, I have been told that for $\ddot I < 0$ the whole system would contract; for $\ddot I < 0$, the system expands; and for $\ddot I = 0$, the system is in an equilibrium state. We get the virial theorem by demanding the system to be in an equilibrium state, thus obtaining
$$ 2 \langle K \rangle + \langle V \rangle + \langle S \rangle =0$$

How can the condition for $\ddot{I}$ be understood? Where does it come from? How can one conclude on the behaviour of the system just by looking at $\ddot I$ ?

It looks to me like the question boils down to the correct interpretation of the scalar moment of inertia: How does it give information about the system size, why is it its second temporal derivative instead of its first?